# Property 'i' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'

Tags: arrays, angularjs, typescript

[i have attached my code here;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkeBC.png)
[i have attached my code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVMwj.png)

i was trying to create delete button to delete array object using ngFor directive

Comment: Please include code and errors as text within the question.

Comment: it's because the button is not inside the`<li>` tag

Answer (score 1):

It should be `index as i` [Reference](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor#description)

Also move the button inside the `li` tag.

```
*ngFor="let post of objectArray; index as i"
```

Comment: actually `let i=index;` works fine, it's just the button out of scope

Answer (score 1):

Please provide a minimal reproduceble example, I'm not going to rewrite your code...
Anyway the problem is here

```html
<ul> 
  <li *ngFor="let post of objectArray; let i= index;">{{post. postTitle}}</li> 
  <button (click) ='onDelete(i)'></button> <!-- should be inside li -->
</ul>
```

#### solution

Simply put the button inside the li tag

```html
<ul> 
  <li *ngFor="let post of objectArray; let i= index;">
    {{post. postTitle}}
    <button (click) ='onDelete(i)'></button>
  </li> 
</ul>
```